# Button is not visible in device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Hi  i am using using below layout code to display title at the top [fixed], text in center [scrollable] and two button in bottom [fixed].

i.e.

```
    -----------------------
   |         Header        |
   |-----------------------|
   |                       |
   | Content goes here     |
   |    (Scrollbale)       |
   |                       |
   |                       |
   |                       |
   |-----------------------|
   | Button 1 |   Button 2 |
   -------------------------
```

I am using below code to generate above layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/intouch_full_border"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/intouch_border_bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Terms and Conditions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/titlesc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:background="@drawable/intouch_full_border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/termsNCondition"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_alert2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/titlesc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Accept"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Move the LinearLayout BEFORE the ScrollView, then add `android:above="@id/linear_alert2"` to the ScrollView. I always use this configuration with my ListViews (Header, Footer and a ListView in between).

Comment: @SimplePlan let me try this

Comment: @rup35h Used `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` and set `linear_alert2` gravity as `Bottom` and set `titlesc` gravity as `center` and set `title` gravity as `Top`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear, I'll try to answer what I thought you were asking.

Change your `ScrollView` to this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/titlesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linear_alert2">
```

Change your Buttons to this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_alert2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/update"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Accept" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```